# How to change the IP address and Port number of Tomcat to some url

Tags: tomcat

I am new to web development. I have created a flex based website and now i want to deploy it in my tomcat server.
I want to change the URL from http://localhost:8080/myapp/ to http://myapp/

Please let me know if somebody has done something similar.

Thanks,
Aj

Answer (score 2):

You can do that through:

- Setting on your router NAT (which can map request to certain IP:port to other IP:port), or
- Setting on your domain name server (be it local or global), or
- Adding a reverse proxy server that can do the translation, this way e.g.

  - Apache Web Server + mod_proxy
  - Apache Web Server + mod_jk
  - Apache Web Server + mod_rewrite
  - IIS + ISAPI
  - nginx
  - Varnish

I'd recommend the 3rd approach, as you don't usually want to expose your Tomcat directly on production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the listen port of the `HttpConnector` in conf/server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Note that giving no port in the URL means port 80, which on Unixoids (like Linux) means that the task that opens the port must run as `root`.

Comment: This takes care of the port issue (i.e., that 80 is the default if none is specified), but that means that you'd still have to say `http://localhost/myapp`, where the OP wants `http://myapp`.